Why does str_replace_all work with named vectors but not with dataframe columns?
I have a dataframe with a column which contains strings representing questionnaire items, which can be expressed as ranges, such as "1:1496,3545:4785" etc. Some of these items have names like "91bis", and I need to convert them to the corresponding progressive number, so that "91bis" -> "92" (it is the first "double" question).
To do the conversion, I am using a dictionary style replacement; here is a sample of the first 100 lines of the dictionary:
dict <- structure(list(q.ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
"97", "98", "99", "100"), q.Voce = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
"61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "91bis", 
"91ter", "92", "93", "93bis", "94", "94bis", "95", "96")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")

Here is what I've tried:
#library(tidyverse)

v <- c("1,91bis,96") #test string of the type found in the dataset

str_replace_all(v,setNames(dict$q.ID,dict$q.Voce))

However, this gives an incorrect result:
[1] "1,7746,8221"

But if I create on purpose a named vector with the correct substitutions, the result is correct:
dict <- setNames(c("1","92","100"),c("1","91bis","96"))

str_replace_all(v,dict)

[1] "1,92,100"

This is the only method that seems to work, everything else throws weird results; does anybody know why?
Many thanks in advance.

For the provided example data I get "1,97,100" as the result which is probably still not your expected result. The issue seems to be that str_replace_all does multiple replacements, i.e. 91bis gets replaced by 92 which gets replaced by 94 and which finally gets replaced by 97.

... for your case you might try with str_replace_all(v, rev(setNames(dict$q.ID, dict$q.Voce))) to replace in the reverse order.

Yes @stefan I think you're right, that's exactly what's happening.  The function replaces the substrings until it can find no other matches in the dictionary keys, so in the example is stops at 97, but if I use the whole dictionary (8309 entries) it goes on, hence the result [1] "1,7746,8221". Unfortunately, reversing the order does not solve the problem..

I have posted another question where the problem is more clearly stated and identified: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78906584/20785124.

I closed as a dup of the second question.
