Str_replace_all behaves strangely when passing a named vector with keys and values in common; what to do?
I have the following problem, which I already brought up in another question: I have a dataframe column with strings expressing single numeric values or ranges of values, like "1:1496,3545:4785,7781" and so on. I also have a dictionary where each numeric value is paired with a progressive ID, such that "91"="91", but "91bis"="92" (the first "double" item). I need to replace each numeric value in the dataframe cells with the progressive ID.
Here is a sample of the dictionary:
dict <- structure(list(q.ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
"97", "98", "99", "100"), q.Voce = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
"61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "91bis", 
"91ter", "92", "93", "93bis", "94", "94bis", "95", "96")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")

EDIT
And here is what I've tried:
#library(stringr)

v <- "1,91bis:94" #example string

str_replace_all(v,setnames(dict$q.ID,dict$q.Voce))

Now, this should return [1] "1,92:97", but actually returns [1] "1,97:97". As the user @stefan pointed out when I first asked the question, this happens because the dictionary keys and values share elements: when the function runs, it inputs "91bis" and converts it to "92", but since 92 is also a value in the dictionary, it is again replaced by "94" and finally by "97". There is no value "97" in the dictionary, so the process stops, but with a larger sample it goes on (I've tried).
Is there any way to prevent this strange behaviour?

It is clear by the comments to SamR's answer that the problem is not reproducible with the current example, so i voted to close the question down

I agree that I probably could have chosen a more fitting example, but if you took the time to read the question, it is clearly stated at the beginning how the data looks like, and I also provided an example ("1:1496,3545:4785,7781").

I don't understand the ranges part. Do you have a string "20:100"? What should be replaced there? Should it be extended to 20,21,22,23,...,100 and there it should replace the numbers? Should it be stored back as range or stay extended?

@AndreWildberg in the ranges I only need to replace the beginning and end with the corresponding values in the dictionary. The reason is because the original values are alphanumeric; once they are all converted to their progressive equivalent, then the ranges can be extended.

Maybe give a sightly more complex example with expected output covering all possibilities (including the ranges).

Regarding why the issue you were facing occurs, see R: Efficient way to str_replace_all without recursively replacing conflicting substitutions? One answer can be adapted to this situation, but it needs substantial changes given the format of your data:
v <- c("1,91bis:94", "1,91bis,94", "1,91bis,96")
# Output should be c("1,92,97", "1,92,97", "1,92,100")
str_replace_all(
    v,
    "(?<=,|^|:).*?(?=,|:|$)",
    \(x) setNames(dict$q.ID, dict$q.Voce)[x]
)
# [1] "1,92:97"  "1,92,97"  "1,92,100"

The regex I think is easiest visualised:

This will replace anything between a comma and a colon (or the start and end of the string) with the values in the dictionary:

(?<=,|^|:): This part looks behind for either a comma, the start of a string, or a colon. The | inside this lookbehind is not replaced with a non-capturing group because lookbehinds don't support alternation within non-capturing groups.
.*?: Non-greedy match of any character as few times as possible.
(?=(?:,|:|$)): A lookahead for a comma, a colon, or the end of the string, without including them in the match.

Unlike using strsplit(), this means there is no information loss about whether the separator was a comma or colon.

I originally started out with a similar approach, but abandoned it because single values are mixed with ranges, and I can't afford to lose that information by collapsing everything with commas.

Find another solution below. It can be beneficial where you need more speed but is less elegant than @SamR solution.
v = c("1,91bis,94", "1,91bis:94", "1,91bis,96", "1,94bis,96", "1,91bis,96")

# subset the rows in dict that are needed for replacements in v 
tb = with(dict, dict[q.ID != q.Voce & q.Voce %in% unlist(strsplit(v, "[,:]")),])
tb = tb[order(tb$q.Voce, decreasing=TRUE),] # useful to properly handle patterns like 91 and 91bis
# replacement
with(tb, Reduce(\(x,i) gsub(q.Voce[i], q.ID[i], x, fixed=T), c(list(v), seq_along(q.Voce))))

[1] "1,92,97"  "1,92:97"  "1,92,100" "1,98,100" "1,92,100"






#### speed test:

set.seed(4934567)
v = sample(c("1,91bis,94", "1,91bis:94", "1,91bis,96", "1,94bis,96", "1,91bis,96"), 1e5, T)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Kamgang = {
    tb = with(dict, dict[q.ID != q.Voce & q.Voce %in% unlist(strsplit(v, "[,:]")),])
    tb = tb[order(tb$q.Voce, decreasing=TRUE),]
    with(tb, Reduce(\(x,i) gsub(q.Voce[i], q.ID[i], x, fixed=T), c(list(v), seq_along(q.Voce))))
  },
  SamR = stringr::str_replace_all(
    v,
    "(?<=,|^|:).*?(?=,|:|$)",
    \(x) setNames(dict$q.ID, dict$q.Voce)[x]
  ),
  times=3L,
  unit="relative"
)

Unit: relative
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 Kamgang  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000     3
    SamR 51.55286 51.12241 51.42632 50.69923 51.36459 52.01984     3

